# Does Vista Voice Recognition engine have scripting like Naturally Speaking?

Tags: scripting, windows-vista, naturallyspeaking

I want to have an action performed whenever the user (while using Vista voice recognition) says "Wingbats are crazy!". How do I do this? Is there scripting or is there a dll to tie into?

Comment: Dear aunt, let's set so double the killer delete select all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check out the [Microsoft Speech API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723627(VS.85).aspx) (SAPI). I used this in Windows XP a while ago and it supports an XML markup that declares the command(s) that you want the system to recognise. Your application then determines what needs to happen when a speech command is recognised.

For speech recognition, check out the [ISpRecoContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms718476(VS.85).aspx) interface.

Previously this was a COM interface, but since Vista you can use .NET. Or apparently you can use [Python](http://surguy.net/articles/speechrecognition.xml) if that's your preference!

### Edit

Microsoft Speech Server 2007 [supports VoiceXML](http://www.microsoft.com/presspass/press/2006/apr06/04-05MSS07BetaPR.mspx), mentioned in another response to this question.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend the [WSR Macro](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=fad62198-220c-4717-b044-829ae4f7c125&displaylang=en) toolkit.  It lets you easily integrate your custom scripts into the Windows Speech Recognition system.  [SAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723627%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [System.Speech.Recognition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.aspx) are great if you need more control, but given your question, I suspect that the learning curve will be much easier with WSR Macros.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Voice XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VoiceXML). A list of systems implementing the standard can be found on [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/Voice/2004/vxml-ir/#systems).